# Help with Lagrange multipliers

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

> I need to find the absolute minima and maxima of the function
> $f(x,y) = 12 x^2 + 12 y^2 - x^3 y^3 -5$ in the region bounded by the disk $x^2 + y^2 \le 1$.

I know that $f(x,y)$ has three critical points in its domain, but only one point of the three, namely $(0,0)$, fits in the region bounded by the disk. This point will be a absolute minimum because $f_{xx}(0,0) >0$ and $f_{yy}(0,0) >0$ and $(0,0)$ is the only minimum in the region bounded by the disk.

Therefore I need to find the other "candidate" points for absolute maximums.

The system of equations for Lagrange Multipliers is the following :
$$
\begin{split}
-3x^2 y^3 + 24x - 2kx &= 0\\
-3y^2 x^3 + 24y - 2ky &= 0\\
 x^2 +y^2 -1 &= 0. 
\end{split}
$$
As you can see, this system of equations is more complex that the typical examples on the internet.What ideas do you have to solve this problems?

Thanks.

Comment: If you do not need to use Lagrange: With polar coordinates the minimum and maximum will almost directly fall into your hands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note the function is symmetric in $x,y$ so the answers are expected to be symmetric as well.

**Case I. $x = 0$**

Then $y = \pm 1$ and you get the points $(0, \pm 1)$.

**Case II. $y = 0$**

Then $x = \pm 1$ and you get the points $(\pm 1, 0)$.

**Case III. $x,y \ne 0$**

Then the first equation can be divided by $x$ and the second by $y$.
Can you finish this case and individually evaluate the candidates?

**UPDATE**

Note in case 3, the system becomes
$$
\begin{split}
-3x y^3 &= 2k - 24\\
-3y x^3 &= 2k - 24\\
 x^2 +y^2 &= 1. 
\end{split}
$$
It immediately follows that $xy^3 = yx^3$ and since $x,y\ne 0$ we divide by $xy$ to get $x^2=y^2$. Use the last constraint to solve.

Comment: Hello, first thanks for the editing, I will try to write better. I did not specify this (and it is my mistake) but it is exactly in case 3 where I am having trouble finding solutions.

Comment: @Ulises Solve for $k$ in both equations.  Then these expressions must be equal.

Comment: @Ulises please see update

Answer (score 0):

Doing what gt6989b adviced in Case III, I find that x= y and -x=y (when I divide by x in the first equation, and by y the second equation, then I proceed to equalize the two resultant equations). Therefore I need to solve the equation of the disk with the constraint x= y and -x=y, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: this should be an update to your question, not an answer. You could have posted it as a comment to my answer as well.

Comment: Thanks. I will learn for the next question.